# List of Logic Symbols

Tags: logic

I was wondering if anyone knows where I could get a list of symbols used in logic and there meaning in english. So far I have found Wikipedias list of logic symbols but other than that I can't find anything. Please help.

Comment: What type of logic are you looking for? If you want a list of the basic symbols used in logic then try http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Logic_Symbols.htm but if you want a list of all of the symbols used through the field of mathematical logic, Wikipedia's page is the closest to that but even still the vast majority of it will be too confusing with no background. What about the Wikipedia page wasn't good enough for what you're looking for? What exactly is it that you want?

Answer (score 2):

Might the trouble be that the symbols do not all have precise natural language equivalents ? For example, '→' does not exactly mean 'if ... then'. If so then the best plan is probably to read a logic text in which the symbols are contextually explained. Perhaps Peter Smith's 'An Introduction to Formal Logic' would be useful but there are any number of reliable and accessible introductions to logic in an academic library or orderable online.

Comment: What about the arrow is different from if... then?

Comment: The symbols → ⊃ ⇒ are all conventionally used for the connective called material implication, or the material conditional. It is a particular kind of conditional and does not in general correctly translate if/then in ordinary English. For an account of the logic of ordinary indicative conditionals, see the Stanford Encyclopedia entry: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/

Answer (score 2):

A few useful resources as far as logical symbols are concerned:

- As mentioned earlier, [list of logic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols) on Wikipedia is a good starting point.
- A more comprehensive list is [logic symbols](https://mathvault.ca/hub/higher-math/math-symbols/logic-symbols/) on Math Vault, with examples for each entry
- For a PDF, this appendix [List of Basic Logic Symbols](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-319-09743-5%2F1.pdf) might come in handy.

And if you're reading a logic book, there might be a similar coverage either on the intro on in the appendix.